# Substract of row count elements in a collection

Tags: c#, list

I have 49 elements in a collection that are displayed in a report. On each page I can display 22 for items (rows)

- Page1 = 22 rows
- Page2 = 22 rows
- Page3 = 5 rows

What I want to do, it's a substraction of 22 - 5 .

But I don't have access to pages because are created dynamically. So how can I do if I want to do this substraction at the beginning from my collection?

22 - (operation to get the last 5 from collection)  = x

If I have 34. Thus, 22 items display on the first page I would get 12 items on the second page. So...

22 - (operation to get the last 12 from collection) = x

I only want the operation to get last rows that don't fit on my last page. Just the number not the object property from my collection.

Comment: Do you just need to do a modulus? `collection.Count % 22`

Comment: 49 % 22 = 1. I want the number 5. Sorry I don't get your answer

Comment: 49 / 22 = 2.  49 - 2*22 = 5. --> `output [5] = input [49] - base [22] * ((int)(input/base))`

Comment: @MaximusDecimus 49 % 22 is 5 not 1.  Did you even try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the remainer, do a modulus, as djs explains.

```
total_rows % rows_per_page = remainder_on_last_page
```

---

```
49 % 22 = 5
34 % 22 = 12
```